# spl_autoload_register and namespaces issue

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

Why this is returning Fatal error: Class 'Mynamespace\String' not found in ...:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'library/');

spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

spl_autoload_register();

Mynamespace\String::myfunc('Test');
```

My library/String.php is:

```
<?php

namespace Mynamespace;

class String
{
    static function myfunc($needle)
    {
        echo $needle;
    }
```

Please not if I remove the namespace it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) without params registers just  [`spl_autoload()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload).

And that default autoloader does not transpose namespaces onto directory names or anything. It just lowercases the received class name, and appends a `.php` suffix. Therefore namespaced classes will only work on Windows, accidentally.

Comment: Check simast at gmail dot com 08-Aug-2009 05:22 in http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

Comment: Only overriding the filename suffix won't change the general issue.